# JSON object containing multiple arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

i have json object that containing json arrays. here is the json object

```
{
"dataset": {
    "id": 11304240,
    "dataset_code": "teste",
    "database_code": "LBMA",
    "name": "testse: London Fixing",
    "description": "test",
    "refreshed_at": "2017-03-17T16:50:32.330Z",
    "newest_available_date": "2017-03-17",
    "oldest_available_date": "1968-01-02",
    "column_names": ["Date", "USD (AM)", "USD (PM)", "GBP (AM)", "GBP (PM)", "EURO (AM)", "EURO (PM)"],
    "frequency": "daily",
    "type": "Time Series",
    "premium": false,
    "limit": 1,
    "transform": null,
    "column_index": null,
    "start_date": "1968-01-02",
    "end_date": "2017-03-17",
    "data": [
        ["2017-03-17", 1228.75, 1229.6, 991.85, 994.25, 1140.53, 1144.27]
        ["2017-03-16", 1228.79, 1228.6, 992.85, 994.25, 1140.53, 1144.27]
    ],
    "collapse": null,
    "order": null,
    "database_id": 139
}
}
```

I need to extract first row of data array to different string and double variables.

so far here is the my solution . i'm getting no data message.

```
  try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
                //JSONObject contacts = jsonArray.getJSONArray("contacts");

                // looping through All Contacts


                    JSONArray js=data.getJSONArray(0);

                    for (int i = 0; i <js.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = js.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("date");
                    String name = c.getString("USD (AM)");
                    String email = c.getString("USD (Pm)");

                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("date", date);
                    contact.put("USD (AM)", am);
                    contact.put("USD (PM)", pm);


                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
```

i'm getting json object from url as string but how can i extract from them to variables?

here is my expected results

```
date = "2017-03-17"
am =  1228.75
pm = 1229.6
```

Comment: Don't you have to go into `dataset` before you can get to `data`?

Comment: do i have to go into that first ?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  The object you've given it has only one field, "dataset".  That field's value is a nested object that has all the other fields.  But I think the `jsonObject` methods will only look at the fields in the object you give it.  They don't do a deep search for nested fields.

Comment: @ajb 'JSONArray js=data.getJSONArray(0);' i came to here. first dataset object , then data arrary then from here js is first row. now how can i go down more ?

Comment: `js.getString(0)`, `js.getDouble(1)`, etc.  Assuming I'm looking at the javadoc for the right class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you may need a class to handle your variables, as your business model require.

Something like:

```
public class DataVo {
   private Date date;
   private Double am;
   private Double pm;

  // getters/setters
}
```

You can create your own service to receive a String and parse it into a list of the DataVo using the code you show.

Or you can use a library like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), creating custom serializers/deserializers to solve your data transformation.

Comment: thank you i will try this one.others are welcome to more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU @AJB and @cleiton it working now.. :)

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONObject dataset = jsonObj.getJSONObject("dataset");

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray data = dataset.getJSONArray("data");
                //JSONObject contacts = jsonArray.getJSONArray("contacts");

                // looping through All Contacts


                    JSONArray js=data.getJSONArray(0);

                    String date = js.getString(0);
                    String am = js.getString(1);
                    String pm =js.getString(2);


                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                contact.put("date", date);
                contact.put("USD (AM)", am);
                contact.put("USD (PM)", pm);

                contactList.add(contact);
```

Answer (score -1):

Create an object to store variables you need!

Comment: An answer like this needs more explanation and/or examples.

Comment: i'm sorry, i think you have known create a object